# XChangeProperty uses long for 32-bits

Tags: c, x11, sparc

The pid variable that is passed to XChangeProperty() is not a long.
The libX11 code deferences the variable as a long and on a 64-bit sparc
this must be aligned on a 8-byte boundary.
Because it is an int, it gets aligned on a 4-byte boundary, causing a 
bus error.

```
pid_t pid = getpid();
XChangeProperty( display, wm_window, net_wm_pid, cardinal, 32,
                 PropModeReplace,
                 (const unsigned char*) &pid, 1 );
```

Its only necessary casts to 'long' or check for max value?

From [XGetWindowProperty(3) manual page](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man3/XGetWindowProperty.3.html)

> format
>               Specifies whether the data should be viewed as a list of
>               8-bit, 16-bit, or 32-bit quantities.  Possible values are
>               8,
>               16, and 32.  This information allows the X server to cor‐
>               rectly perform byte-swap operations as necessary.  If the
>               format is 16-bit or 32-bit, you must explicitly cast your
>               data pointer to an (unsigned char *) in the call to
>               XChange‐
>               Property.

```
pid_t pid = getpid ();
if (pid <= 0xFFFFFFFFU) {
    unsigned long xpid = pid;

    XChangeProperty( display, wm_window, net_wm_pid, cardinal, 32,
                     PropModeReplace,
                     (const unsigned char*) &xpid, 1 );
}
```

Comment: Is `sizeof( pid_t )` less than or equal to `sizeof( unsigned long )`?  If so, how could a `pid_t` value possibly be greater than `MAX_ULONG`?

Comment: I don't get it. That second to last arg of XChangeProperty is a pointer-to-char and as such has absolutely no alignment restrictions. You suspect a libX11 bug? As a workaround you could try a union with an 8 byte aligned member and a pid_t.

Comment: @Jens There will be code elsewhere, inside a library/window manager/etc. that recovers this pointer-to-char, and that's where the issue is, if that code does e.g. `long l = *(long*)char_ptr;` and the pointer is not suitable aligned to be accessed as a long.

Comment: Also, what `libX11.so` are you using?  One you've compiled, or the OS-supplied one?  If you're running Solaris on SPARC, you can use Oracle's [Studio compiler](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5265/bjavc/index.html) and compile everything with `-xmemalign=1i`.  In this case, you'd have to compile `libX11.so`.

Answer (score 4):

You have to pass a long to XChangeProperty for 32 bit properties you're setting.

So you need to do

```
unsigned long xpid = pid;
```

If your `pid_t` is 32 bits or less, there's no need to check if it's <= 0xFFFFFFFFU, it will always be true.

If you want your code to be portable to systems that have pid_t values > 32 bits - (though I don't know of any system that has) then you need that check since the _NET_WM_PID property is defined to be 32 bits.

The underlying issue here is that libX11 will dereference the property as a `long`, but only extract 32 bit from it, so from what I can tell _NET_WM_PID can't be used on a system if the pid_t value is > 32 bits.

Now, the reason for all this is that X11 was made in a time that where long was 32 bits on all systems it needed to run on, and has been kept that way to not break its API and ABI, I'll quote from [this post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fltkcoredev/xe3m8d9P8ic)

> You have to separate the C API from the underlying X11 objects.  The
>   objects are 32-bit (or 16 or 8), and will always remain so. These 
>   have to be mapped to the language (C) somehow. The types picked
>   matched  up nicely for a few decades, but unfortunately not anymore.
>   So rather  than backpeddling and saying "we didn't really mean long,
>   we meant  whatever-type-is-closest-to-32-bit-right-now", they kept
>   long. Anything  else would probably have meant a very painful
>   transition period.
>
> That means that everything in the X11 API that deals with 32-bit 
>   objects will use 64-bit variables with half the space wasted.

Comment: Nice find.  I was wondering about that when I posted my first comment to the question.  "What?  It says 32-bit but it's a 64-bit `long` parameter?!?!"  I figured it had to date back to maybe even the "16-bit `int`, 32-bit `long`" days.